# postgres table insert identity by type

Tags: postgresql, postgres-14

I have a table like below with versionid (uuid) and productid (int). both are inserted by an application. I would like to add a versionnum int column that will work like an identity column, but per productid:

```
+-----------+-----------+------------+----+
| versionid | productid | versionnum | id |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----+
| guid...1  | 345       | 1          | 1  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----+
| guid...2  | 345       | 2          | 2  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----+
| guid...3  | 345       | 3          | 3  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----+
| guid...4  | 789       | 1          | 4  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----+
| guid...5  | 345       | 4          | 5  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----+
| guid...6  | 789       | 2          | 6  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----+
| guid...7  | 345       | 5          | 7  |
+-----------+-----------+------------+----+
```

Is there a lightweight way to insert the versionnum with the other two columns?

The best solution I can think is to add an actual identity column id, at least you'd know productid 789 would have versionnum 4 & 6. But I would like a way for each product to have a sequential id

Thanks

Comment: What's the `id` column? Is it guaranteed to be ordered like that?

Comment: You'd use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productid ORDER BY id)` for this, when querying. It is not possible to use an identity column for this.